# Why a constant escapes to heap in golang?

Tags: go, constants, heap-memory

Here is my golang code to set a key C to value 1 in redis

It uses third party code in order to connect to redis.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis"
)

func main() {

    c, err := redis.Dial("tcp", ":6379")

    _, err = c.Do("SET", "C", 1)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

On doing `go build -gcflags "-m -m"`, it reports

> ./del.go:41: 1 escapes to heap
>
> ./del.go:41:  from c.Do("SET", "C", 1) (parameter to indirect call) at
>   ./del.go:41

Why does 1 escape to the heap ? It is a simple constant whose complete information is known at compile time and it takes just 64bits on a 64bit system. Why should it be stored in heap memory?

Comment: could you provide full code?

Comment: @TheName I have updated it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The signature of `Do` is:

`Do(commandName string, args ...interface{}) (reply interface{}, err error)`

Because `args` is a variadic (slice of) `interface{}` it's heap allocated.

I believe there could be some optimisations in the pipeline for simple cases like this in future versions of Go: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15528